# Rails Tutorial 3 : Can't get app to work after section 9.3.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been faithfully been following along with Rails Tutorial 3 and been loving it but am totally stuck with where I've gone wrong after section 9.3.3. Signin Success -> Current user.

I run the rspec tests rspec/spec but have one failure in my sessions_helper.

For some reason the controller.current_user doesn't == @user and I can't for the life of me figure out where I went wrong or why this doesn't work. I understand where things got to for it to fail but can't work out why.

What's more frustrating to me as I'm starting out with rails is I don't know where to even start trying to debug this or what the debugging process is.

I would be eternally grateful if anyone wanted to take on the challenge of forking this from my github [https://github.com/markstewie/railstut_sampleapp][1] and trying to work out the problem. I would be even more grateful if anyone could explain the process you would go through to debug a problem like this... I'm seriously stumped.

/////////////////// SOLUTION /////////////////////////

Sorry guys, I've just found the problem!!! At last...

in session_helper I had.

```
  def remember_token
     cookies.signed(:remember_token) || [nil,nil]
```

rather than

```
  def remember_token
     cookies.signed[:remember_token] || [nil,nil]
```

This has been by far the hardest section to understand and I still don't fully but at least it's working now.

Thanks for your time!
Mark.

Comment: The tests seem to pass for me. I cloned your repository, then ran 'bundle install', 'rake db:migrate' and 'rake spec'. It ran '51 examples, 0 failures'.

Comment: you should post your solution as an answer (the bottom of the page) so others know this question has been closed and also so your answer acceptance % stays high

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just been struggling with the same section, here's what I found:

Make sure that in sessions_helper.rb you have both the `current_user=(user)` method from **listing 9.15** and the improved `current_user` method from **listing 9.16**

and

I had to modify the `signed_in?` method in session_helper.rb like this:

```
  def signed_in?  
    !self.current_user.nil?  
  end
```

There is actually a remark about changing `current_user` to `self.current_user` in **footnote 9.6**, though that seems to be related to some other section.

HTH

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for that. Yep, have all of that in and the test still fails :( Thanks for trying to help out though.

Answer (score 1):

Cloned your rep, run bundle install, migrated the database und run rake rspec. All your tests pass. Can you show your output?

Edit: This was the output

```
77:test2 markus$ rake spec
(in /Users/markus/Dropbox/Rails/test2)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -S bundle exec rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb ./spec/models/user_spec.rb ./spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb ./spec/requests/users_spec.rb
No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
...................................................

Finished in 3.81 seconds
51 examples, 0 failures
```

Comment: Hey Markus, Really sorry mate. Forgot I was working on a branch that I didn't push up to github. That branch is there now called 'sign-in-out'. If you clone that it should throw the error I'm referring to. Thanks for taking the time to look at this. Really appreciate it.